# How to detect angular2 web application is in test mode

Tags: angular, protractor, e2e-testing

How can I from within an angular2 runtime detect that I am running in e2e test mode? I have a session refresh interval that I do not want to set up when in test mode to avoid synchronization problems with protractor.

An obvious answer would be to look for a URL parameter. Is there a less dirty solution?

EDIT (clarification before bounty):
Protractor is wired to angular (1 or 2) in such way that it will wait for all outstanding work to finish before evaluating anything. That means that all outstanding angular `promises` or any active angular `timer` will hang protractor tests (and eventually cause them to fail). The most commonly proposed solution is to set `browser.ignoreSynchronization = true` but that would force me to either nest all e2e tests in callback-chains or use a bunch of sleeps. Probably both. So it seems I am stuck between a rock and a hard place either having a real uphill experience writing e2e tests or setting a condition around a particular line of application code to not run when in "test mode" (eww, ugly). I choose to have easier e2e test as I expect to write them in the hundreds and so far we are only talking about one interval that isn't critical during testing (30 minute interval for session refresh).

Comment: Getting environment from global variables (e.g. ENV) is pretty much common.

Comment: I am using `browser.ignoreSynchronization = true` with Angular2 and don't have to wait for the models to resolve after a change. Can you describe a sample when `browser.ignoreSynchronization = true`  is a problem and forces you to sleep?

Comment: @JuanmiRodriguez Everytime something asynchronous is done. Such as changing "page" or fetching data over the network.

Comment: Ok, I actually like to stub and simulate or explicitly wait for in those samples. I see your point, but making the code to behave differently in test mode looks like a door for entropy in your code as more code is added in the future to this conditional... (and if can be done and it is faster, it will be done...)

Comment: Well.. for proper e2e testing I do not want to stub or simulate anything. Failure-frequency will be higher but the capture net will be wider which is what I want. Ideally code will be run exactly as is during e2e testing so I agree with you on opening the entropy door. But as I said, between a rock and a hard place.

Comment: @estus What is the preferred way to obtain an environment variable from within the Angular code? Are you referring to a UNIX-style environment variable, or an Angular2-style environment object?

Comment: @torazaburo In this [highly popular boilerplate](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular-starter/blob/df97df77798be867022513bb151fe3ea467d833d/src/app/environment.ts#L27) it's used as global string variable that is set by Webpack.

Comment: @estus. Thanks. But that requires us angular-cli folks to eject, right?

Comment: @torazaburo Yes, that's raw Webpack project. As for Angular CLI,this is even simpler, see http://tattoocoder.com/angular-cli-using-the-environment-option/ for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start your timeouts/intervals outside of angulars zone through

```
ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
  // start your timeout/interval here
});
```

This will avoid protractor waiting for the timeout/interval to finish. For more information see: https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/3349

Answer (score 1):

one obvious solution i think is setting a global Variable on window object

```
if(window.TEST_MODE){
   // run code that needs to be run during test
}
```

In your test code set

```
window.TEST_MODE = true;
```

Comment: While that would work, it is basically just a dirtier solution than what @estus proposed with using environment variables and that will be the solution I'll work towards.
Having an configuration variable, say, `useSessionRefresh = true` and have that be `false` when using the e2e test config will do. Also, that won't clutter the production code with a lot of window.TEST_MODE and could potentially be a valuable configuration in itself.

Comment: I agree , my solution was just a temporary though , if you were in hurry